# HttpWebRequest Grinding to a halt, possibly just due to page size

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I have WPF app that processes a lot of urls (thousands), each it sends off to it's own thread, does some processing and stores a result in the database.

The urls can be anything, but some seem to be massively big pages, this seems to shoot the memory usage up a lot and make performance really bad. I set a timeout on the web request, so if it took longer than say 20 seconds it doesn't bother with that url, but it seems to not make much difference.

Here's the code section:

```
               HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlAddress.Address);
                            req.Timeout = 20000;
                            req.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000;
                            req.Method = "GET";
                            req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                pageSource = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                req = null;
                            }
```

It also seems to stall/ramp up memory on reader.ReadToEnd();

I would have thought having a cut off of 20 seconds would help, is there a better method? I assume there's not much advantage to using asynch web method as each url download is on its own thread anyway..

Thanks

Comment: One of the random urls I picked out as being a problem is http://www.rfkbau.de/index.php?option=com_easybook&Itemid=22&startpage=7096

Comment: That url will probably kill your browser after a minute or so of loading, at least it did mine

Comment: how many threads you are running at same time?

Comment: As many as the machine can handle, thousands of threads get created an queued up. Think the default is something like 100?

Comment: I'd not recommend you do that... If you use 100 threads at same time of course your CPU will be having a problem with that. I'd suggest you to use no more than 30 threads at a time or maybe 50 max...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [it's recommended that you use asynchronous HttpWebRequests](http://www.matlus.com/httpwebrequest-asynchronous-programming/) instead of creating your own threads. The article I've linked above also includes some benchmarking results.

I don't know what you're doing with the page source after you read the stream to end, but [using string can be an issue](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-optimize-memory-usage-with.html):

> System.String type is used in any .NET application. We have strings
>   as: names, addresses, descriptions, error messages, warnings or even
>   application settings. Each application has to create, compare or
>   format string data. Considering the immutability and the fact that any
>   object can be converted to a string, all the available memory can be
>   swallowed by a huge amount of unwanted string duplicates or unclaimed
>   string objects.

Some other suggestions:

- **Do you have any firewall restrictions?** I've seen a lot of issues at work where the firewall enables rate limiting and fetching pages grinds down to a halt (happens to me all the time)!
- I presume that you're going to use the string to parse HTML, so I would recommend that you initialize your parser with the `Stream` instead of passing in a string containing the page source (if that's an option).
- If you're storing the page source in the database, then there isn't much you can do.
- Try to eliminate the reading of the page source as a potential contributor to the memory/performance problem by commenting it out.
- **Use a streaming HTML parser** such as [Majestic 12](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php)- avoids the need to load the entire page source into memory (again, *if you need to parse*)!
- Limit the size of the pages you're going to download, say, only download 150KB. [The average page size is about 100KB-130KB](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/average-web-page/)

Additionally, can you tell us what's your initial rate of fetching pages and what does it go down to? Are you seeing any errors/exceptions from the web request as you're fetching pages?

### Update

In the comment section I noticed that you're creating thousands of threads and I would say that you don't need to do that. Start with a small number of threads and keep increasing them until you peek the performance on your system. Once you start adding threads and the performance looks like it's tapered off, then sop adding threads. I can't imagine that you will need more than 128 threads (even that seems high). Create a fixed number of threads, e.g. 64, let each thread take a URL from your queue, fetch the page, process it and then go back to getting pages from the queue again.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, once it's downloaded the page it runs through several keywords/phrases to look for in a page(could be 100+), for each it examines the page and if it finds matches it updates the database for that url, doesn't store the actual page content. Yeah at the moment it uses the string source of the page

Comment: The main speed issue does seem to be the reader read: "pageSource = reader.ReadToEnd();" taking that out stops the memory from going a bit crazy and speeds it up quite a lot

Comment: @JimmySavile sounds good! So you shouldn't need to save the entire page source to do what you're describing. You should be able to do a buffered read and also consider reading a much smaller portion of the website if your situation permits it. Try focusing on potential areas where you can find the strings that you're looking for (i.e. in between `<body></body>` tags, etc.).

Comment: As far as the speed issue goes, can you elaborate on the behavior? How fast do you fetch at first? What does it slow down to? Have you checked the network firewall for rate limiting (the usual problem at my office)? Do you get any errors/exceptions when your speed goes down?

Comment: It's only limited by the number of threads the machine lets it use and the internet connection, memory was getting up to the system's max, whereas without that line it stays low. Still if I put that url that causes problems in that I mention above it, takes minutes to fully load even with the 20 sec timeout. Only on a win 7 laptop, so don't think the firewall is causing any issues

Comment: @JimmySavile cool... so think about not loading the entire page and if you absolutely need to, then use a buffered read. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. For anyone not realising, the req.Timeout and req.ReadWriteTimeout settings are combined, timeoue is how long it waits to connect in the first place then how long to wait to read data, might be obvious but I didn't realise for a while

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate with a buffer instead of calling ReadToEnd, and if it is taking too long, then you could log and abandon - something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Uri largeUri = new Uri("http://www.rfkbau.de/index.php?option=com_easybook&Itemid=22&startpage=7096");
  DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
  int timeoutSeconds = 10;
  foreach (var s in ReadLargePage(largeUri))
  {
    if ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds > timeoutSeconds)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Stopping - this is taking too long.");
      break;
    }

  }
}

static IEnumerable<string> ReadLargePage(Uri uri)
{            
  int bufferSize = 8192;
  int readCount;
  Char[] readBuffer = new Char[bufferSize];
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri); 
  using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
  {
    readCount = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (readCount > 0)
    {
      yield return new string(readBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
      readCount = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lirik has really good summary.

I would add that if I were implementing this, I would make a separate process that reads the pages. So, it would be a pipeline. First stage would download the URL and write it to a disk location. And then queue that file to the next stage. Next stage reads from the disk and does the parsing & DB updates. That way you will get max throughput on the download and parsing as well. You can also tune your threadpools so that you have more workers parsing, etc. This architecture also lends very well to distributed processing where you can have one machine downloading, and another host parsing/etc.

Another thing to note is that if you are hitting the same server from multiple threads (even if you are using Async) then you will hit yourself against the max outgoing connection limit. You can throttle yourself to stay below that, or increase the connection limit on the ServicePointManager class.